# How do i eliminate redundancy

Tags: php, mysql

How do I avoid redundant insertion of data in mysql table eg in Id 003

```
STUDENT ID              SUBJECT
003                     MATHS
003                     MATHS
004                     ENGLISH
003                     MATHS
004                     SCIENCE
```

Comment: You can define `STUDENT ID` as `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE INDEX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database can validate the data for you, using a unique index or constraint (which are functionally equivalent):

```
create unique index idx_t_student_subject on t(student, subject);
```

You can also define this as a constraint when you create the table:

```
create table t (
    . . .
    constraint unq_t_student_subject unique (student, subject)
    . . .
);
```

When you attempt to insert a duplicate row, you'll get an error.

Note:  a primary key would have the same effect, as well as defining each column as `NOT NULL`.